# Why doesn't this conditional statement compile?

Tags: java

For a CodingBat exercise, I have to see which of two int values is closest to 10, but it keeps giving me an error and I'm unsure why.

The error I'm getting is this:

> The method `abs(int)` in the class `Math` is not applicable for the arguments (`boolean`)

```
public int close10(int a, int b) {
    int m;
    if (Math.abs(a - 10 > b - 10)) // here is the error
        m = b;
    else
        m = a;

    return m;
}
```

Comment: You need `Math.abs(a - 10) > Math.abs(b - 10)`. Right now you're asking for the absolute value of the boolean expression `a - 10 > b - 10`, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement within the `Math.abs` call is being evaluated to a `boolean` (`a - 10 > b - 10` will either be `true` or `false`), but there is no such method as `Math.abs(boolean)`

Perhaps you should use something more like...

```
if (Math.abs(a - 10) > Math.abs(b - 10)) {...}
```

...instead

Answer (score 1):

try `Math.abs(a - 10) > Math.abs(b - 10)`

Comment: This answer is too short according to SO standards. Try to improve it adding some additional explanations and turn it into a quality answer useful also for other users, not only for the question's OP.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a - 10 > b - 10` has a `boolean` value, that's what the compiler is saying. Maybe you'll want something like:

```
Math.abs(a - 10) > Math.abs(b - 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Math.abs` method twice, while you only use it once:

```
    if (Math.abs(a - 10) > Math.abs(b - 10))
```

You can't preform an operation like `Math.abs` on a condition statement like `a - 10 > b - 10`, it just doesn't make an logical sense, as you can see.
Also, on a side note, I'd recommend some more formatting in your code, its a bit awkward.